# Add 12 future dates in a row Based on given date - Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I Have a dataframe like this

[image]

I would want 12 future dates based on the Freq which is days

[image]

I have tried adding this in loop and _append

```
df['next_d']._append(df['date'] + pd.Timedelta(30,unit='days')).to_frame())
```

I learnt using to_frame() here will not work.I am bit confused here doing this by pd.date_range()
Please advise!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the data is only given via screenshots I had to make some assumptions. I supposed your dates are `datetime.date` types.

I was then able to reconstruct the original dataset in the `data` dict.

From there it is a simple few conditions to duplicate the dates with longer timedeltas added:

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


data = [
    {"id": 1, "date": datetime(2023, 10, 1).date(), "freq": 30},
    {"id": 2, "date": datetime(2023, 10, 2).date(), "freq": 30},
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Preparing this to add our new dates
futures = []

for _, row in df.iterrows():
    if row["freq"] > 0:
        for i in range(1,13):
            futures.append(
                {"id": row["id"], "date": row["date"] + timedelta(days=30*i), "freq": 0}
            )

df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(futures)])
```

Here is the final result:

```
    id        date  freq
0    1  2023-10-01    30
1    2  2023-10-02    30
0    1  2023-10-31     0
1    1  2023-11-30     0
2    1  2023-12-30     0
3    1  2024-01-29     0
4    1  2024-02-28     0
5    1  2024-03-29     0
6    1  2024-04-28     0
7    1  2024-05-28     0
8    1  2024-06-27     0
9    1  2024-07-27     0
10   1  2024-08-26     0
11   1  2024-09-25     0
12   2  2023-11-01     0
13   2  2023-12-01     0
14   2  2023-12-31     0
15   2  2024-01-30     0
16   2  2024-02-29     0
17   2  2024-03-30     0
18   2  2024-04-29     0
19   2  2024-05-29     0
20   2  2024-06-28     0
21   2  2024-07-28     0
22   2  2024-08-27     0
23   2  2024-09-26     0
```